# SQL Server Row Number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to implement row numbering based on the sample below:

```
StartOfWeek Total   RowNumber
-----------------------------
1/17/2016   8       1
1/24/2016   8       1
1/31/2016   10      2
2/7/2016    10      2
2/14/2016   14      3
2/21/2016   10      4
2/28/2016   10      4
```

How can I achieve this? I tried dense_rank but can't seem to get the expected RowNumber.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried. Also, it's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Elaborating on @mituw16's comment, it is not obvious what logic is used to calculate `RowNumber`. A naive guess could be "when, ordered by `StartOfWeek`, the value of `Total` changes, increment `RowNumber`" Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: what is RowNumber referring to?

Comment: `DENSE_RANK` should do exactly this ([MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)).  Can you post what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CTE for this and a Self Join

```
CREATE TABLE test (
     StartOfWeek DATETIME,
     Total INT
    )
INSERT  INTO test
VALUES  ('1/17/2016',8),
        ('1/24/2016',8),
        ('1/31/2016',10),
        ('2/7/2016',10),
        ('2/14/2016',14),
        ('2/21/2016',10),
        ('2/28/2016',10)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY StartOfWeek) Rn
    FROM    test
)
SELECT  c1.StartOfWeek,
        c1.Total,
        -- incremement by 1 if Total value changes
        SUM(CASE WHEN c1.Total= c2.Total THEN 0 
                 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY c1.Rn) AS RowNumber
FROM    cte c1
        LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.Rn = c2.Rn + 1

Result

StartOfWeek             Total       RowNumber
----------------------- ----------- -----------
2016-01-17 00:00:00.000 8           1
2016-01-24 00:00:00.000 8           1
2016-01-31 00:00:00.000 10          2
2016-02-07 00:00:00.000 10          2
2016-02-14 00:00:00.000 14          3
2016-02-21 00:00:00.000 10          4
2016-02-28 00:00:00.000 10          4
```

Comment: I did not test this but it seems like it would start on zero

Comment: @LaurenceSurat This CTE is pretty overkill, you should be able to do this with `dense_rank() over (order by Total)`

Comment: @iamdave dense_rank won't do this...  he wants it ordered by date and have the RowNumber change only when the total changes.  Notice that RowNumbers 2 & 4 both have Total = 10